# NGen errors with assembly dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, ngen, google-api-dotnet-client, assembly-binding-redirect

I have an issue that is apparently not new, but one that I still can't seem to find an answer to yet.

I am using Google's Analytics API for .NET and am having a rough time trying to get the assemblies to play nicely together. I don't get any build errors when I build through Visual Studio 2012. However, when I start using NGen to precompile the projects, I see a lot of bad assembly references.

I'm using MVC 4, Visual Studio 2012, and the latest Google.Apis packages (1.5.0.1-beta as of right now).

The .dll's / versions I have installed in the project in question are:

```
DotNetOpenAuth, Version 4.0.0.11165  
System.Web.Mvc, Version 4.0.0.0  
System.Net.Http.Primitives, Version 4.2.13.0  
log4net, Version 1.2.11.0
Google.Apis, Version 1.5.0.1-beta
```

Here are the errors I am finding in NGen's output:

`Failed to load dependency System.Net.Http.Primitives of assembly Google.Apis, Version=1.4.0.28227, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null because of the following error : The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)`

`Failed to load dependency System.Web.Mvc of assembly DotNetOpenAuth, Version=4.0.0.11165, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246 because of the following error : The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)`

`Failed to load dependency log4net of assembly DotNetOpenAuth, Version=4.0.0.11165, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246 because of the following error : The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)`

And here is what I have in that project's web.config:

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="log4net" publicKeyToken="669e0ddf0bb1aa2a" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.2.11.0" newVersion="1.2.11.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Primitives" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.13.0" newVersion="4.2.13.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

I believe that most of that was built out when I used NuGet to install the Google.Apis packages, but I can't figure out why the assembly binding redirects aren't preventing these errors from NGen.

If anyone could help point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it! Thank you!

Comment: Because I'm seeing this over and over again, I just contact the owners of the HttpClient NuGet package, and asked them if they are familiar with similar issues. Hopefully I'll be able to update soon.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried supplying your application's config file to NGEN using /ExeConfig?  For a web app you may need to copy the web.config to app.exe.config and pass in a path to a non-existent app.exe in your web-app directory.

Comment: That sounds pretty promising, but I'm not sure what file to supply to /ExeConfig. When I build the solution, I don't get an .exe out in the \bin directory. Should I be looking elsewhere or is there a Visual Studio setting I need to go look at?

Comment: The idea would be to fake up an app.config and pass that to NGEN. You can probably just copy your web.config and remove everything but the binding redirects. BTW: How do you currently NGEN your web application?

Comment: @ImmoLandwerth, My NGen looks similar to this, just replacing /path/project to my real project's destination:

`SET PATH=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319`


`for %%i in (C:\path\project\bin\*.dll) do ngen install "%%i"`


`pause`

Comment: @TheESJ, I created a new file "MyProject.exe" and put in the assembly bindings from the project. Added that to the /ExeConfig option, but I get a "Failed to load the runtime" error on all the DLLs in that project. How should that .exe file I created look? To be more specific, it looks exactly like the web.config sample I put in the original question, just with the XML declaration, and <configuration> </configuration> surrounding the <runtime> tags.

Comment: @TheESJ, I think I misread your answer. I also tried creating "MyProject.exe.config" and referencing "MyProject.exe" in /ExeConfig but I got a file not found. Is there some sort of virtual path that I need to set up or something for that to work?

Comment: I should have tested my answer, sorry about that.  Here are the steps that worked for me:
copy webapp.dll app.exe,
copy web.config app.exe.config,
ngen install webapp.dll /ExeConfig:app.exe

Comment: [Here's](https://gist.github.com/jtheisen/c7cd84d1c66598b045a360cca9ba8ef4) a snippet for msbuild to create those two files on each build and give the ngen command to be run in the build output for convenience. Thanks for the great answer.